# Beautiful Soup Find - get just the text

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup

I had this bit of code spitting out just the price as a string (125.01), but I must have changed something because now it prints the whole line with the html tags and everything. How can i get it to print out just the text, without using regular expressions?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=aapl&fr=uh3_finance_web&uhb=uhb2'

data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content)
price = soup.find("span", {'id':'yfs_l84_aapl'})
print(price)


<span id="yfs_l84_aapl">125.01</span>
```

Comment: Solved. I added .get_text() method and it worked. Thanks @halex

Answer (score 6):

You have to call the [`get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method of your `price` variable:

```
print(price.get_text())
```

Comment: Or possibly `price.text`. The difference is that if the `span` sometimes has HTML formatting (e.g., it's red for negative amounts), `text` will concat the text of all sub-tags, while `get_text()` returns just the immediate text. If you don't expect that to ever happen, `get_text()` is probably the one you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and accurate answer!

Answer (score 2):

You use `get_text()` on your soup tag.

```
print(price.get_text())
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and accurate answer!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I've found that `.text` or `.get_text()` return an empty string and I have to use:

`print(price.contents[0])`

I think it has to do with unicode vs bytes being returned.